# SQL GROUP BY and a condition on COUNT

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL expression:

```
select id, count(oID) from MyTable group by oID;
```

and I get something like

```
+-------+---------------+
| id    | count(oID)    |
+-------+---------------+
|   002 |             6 |
|   104 |             1 |
|   101 |             1 |
|   908 |             1 |
+-------+---------------+
```

And now I'd like to pull out the rows (select id) where `count(oID)` is 1. How can I do this in one SQL statement?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a `HAVING` clause to filter an aggregated column.

```
SELECT   id, count(oID) 
FROM     MyTable 
GROUP BY oID 
HAVING   count(oID) = 1
```

**UPDATE 1**

wrap the results in a subquery

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableName a INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT   id 
        FROM     MyTable 
        GROUP BY id  
        HAVING   count(oID) = 1
    ) b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: I have those same id's in another table. How could I join this result so that I pull up rows that have the same id in another table?

Comment: Don't you need to `GROUP BY id` rather than `GROUP BY oID` (in both queries)?